# How to support IAP subscription free trial in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have auto-renewable subscription. I added the introductory offers free-trial - 1 week.

My code:

```
class IAPManager:NSObject {

    static let shared = IAPManager()
    private override init() {    }

    var products: [SKProduct] = []
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

    public func setupPurchases(callback: @escaping(Bool) -> ()) {
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            paymentQueue.add(self)
            callback(true)
            return
        }
        callback(false)
    }

    public func getProducts() {
        let identifiers: Set = [
            IAPProducts.auto.rawValue
        ]

        let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: identifiers)
        productRequest.delegate = self
        productRequest.start()
    }

    public func purchase(productWith identifier: String) {
        guard let product = products.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == identifier }).first else { return }

        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        paymentQueue.add(payment)
    }

    public func restoreCompletedTransactions() {
        paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
}
extension IAPManager: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .deferred: break
            case .purchasing: break
            case .failed: failed(transaction: transaction)
            case .purchased: completed(transaction: transaction)
            case .restored: restored(transaction: transaction)
            }
        }
    }

    private func failed(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        if let transactionError = transaction.error as NSError? {
            if transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
                print("Ошибка транзакции: \(transaction.error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        paymentQueue.finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    private func completed(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("success")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(transaction.payment.productIdentifier), object: nil)
        paymentQueue.finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

    private func restored(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        paymentQueue.finishTransaction(transaction)
    }
}



extension IAPManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.products = response.products
        print(self.products.count)
        products.forEach { print($0.localizedTitle) }
    }
}
```

How do I send to the Apple server that the user chose a free-trial subscription? For auto-renewable subscription I just call:

```
iapManager.purchase(productWith: identifier)
```

How do I activate the free-trial subscription?

Comment: Don't verify the purchase receipt until the trial period is over after the very first launch?

Answer (score 1):

The free trial is managed automatically by Apple - you just need to configure it on the product in App Store Connect. Apple will allow one free trial per user per subscription group. You just purchase the product normally.

Comment: ty, how can I check if the trial version has passed?

Comment: The `is_trial_period` in the receipt file: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

Answer (score 1):

A clarification: if you use the `Apple App Store Connect` website to define, say, a free trial on a particular auto-renewable subscription, the free trial will be applied automatically the first time that subscription is purchased (through the subscription `SKProduct`). There is no way to allow a user to either skip the associated trial and purchase a paid subscription right away or activate only the associated free trial for that subscription. When a free trial is applied automatically, the iOS purchase confirmation alert reads: "*Subscribe to {some} Auto Renewable Subscription. Free for {some time} starting now. Automatically renews for {some price} starting {some date}.*"